# Master menu is not visible on mobile devices but is visible on tablet

Tags: sapui5

I have created a split app using the `sap.m.SplitApp` control.

**Mobile Device:**

[image]

**iPad:**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is the intended behaviour.

See this github issue: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/30

One of the devs says

> The SplitApp is designed to behave like e.g. the "Settings" app on iPhone, where a master-detail structure on tablet is mapped to a linear set of pages on phone. As such it is correct not to display a "Show Master" button.

However, they suggest the following

> On phones there is no master button, but you should initially see the master area and navigate from there to the detail area by selecting items.

To achieve this you can do the following: Your detail pages should contain a button with which you can navigate back to the master view (this button should only be visible if the device is a phone):

```xml
<Page id="detailPage" showNavButton="{device>/isPhone}" navButtonPress="handleNavButtonPress">
</Page>
```

The `navButtonPress` handler is implemented in your detail view's controller

```js
handleNavButtonPress: function () {
    var oSplitApp = this.getView().getParent().getParent();
    var oMaster = oSplitApp.getMasterPages()[0];
    oSplitApp.toMaster(oMaster, "flip");
}
```

---

The `device` model I used can be implemented as follows (place this code in the `init` of your `Component.js`

```js
var deviceModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
    isPhone: sap.ui.Device.system.phone
});
this.setModel(deviceModel, "device");
```

See this resource for further information: http://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/32/5b8edafcfa4c9c8fbd42455a60e379/content.htm

Comment: Nice..!! Working..!!

Comment: There should be no difference between different OS?!

Comment: I'm not quite sure if that is the right solution for the problem. I'm also working on the showing-Master-view-of-a-splitapp behavior, but in my case, using the suggested solution, I get the error "Object Element sap.m.Page#__page0 has no method 'getView'".

Comment: Well it may depend on how you structured your views/controllers. When you debug the `handleNavButtonPress` method then `this` should point to your detail controller (since it's a basic event handler). In your case `this` seems to be a `sap.m.Page` (which is the content of your view rather than the controller)

Comment: My problem is quite different, so I've posted a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40718078/master-menu-is-not-visible-on-mobile-devices-but-is-visible-on-internetexplorer

Answer (score 0):

hi every one i found the solution: 
on XML view  : you must put true to the property showheader  for the page ypu want to see the button fo navigate and implemet the handle method for mavigate

```
<Page id="detail"
        showHeader="true"
       showNavButton = "true"  navButtonPress = "handleNav"
```